# Asymptotic behaviour of $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{R_{k+1}+R_k}{R_{k+1}-R_k}$, where $R_k$ are the Ramanujan primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, sequences-and-series, asymptotics, prime-constellations

I was inspired in the following post from this Math Overflow that was asked yerterday [*Asymptotic behavior of a certain sum of ratios of consecutives primes*](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351875/asymptotic-behavior-of-a-certain-sum-of-ratios-of-consecutives-primes) to ask about a similar question for ratios involving Ramanujan primes $R_n$.

As motivation (I think that) Ramanujan primes have a special importance in the theory of prime gaps, thus I think that this series should be also interesting and a good companion of the question asked yesterday. I add as reference this Wikipedia [*Ramanujan prime.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_prime)

> **Question.** We denote the sequence of Ramanujan primes as $R_k$. What work can be done about the asymptotic behaviour of $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{R_{k+1}+R_k}{R_{k+1}-R_k}$$
>   as $n\to\infty$? I'm asking if you can improve/refute my calculations below, adding what statement (in Landau notation or as an asymptotic equivalence) you can to get.  **Many thanks.**

The part that I know is that using Sondow's asymptotic and the comment of one of  the professors of the mentioned MO post **351875** the quotient in our series should be roughly $$\frac{(4k+1)\log(2k)+2(k+1)\log\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)}{2\log(2k)+2(k+1)\log\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)}$$
and from this, and that $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{4k+1}{2}=n^2+\frac{3n}{2}$, my guess that (Vinogradov's notation)

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{R_{k+1}+R_k}{R_{k+1}-R_k}\ll\left(n^2+\frac{3n}{2}\right)\log\log n$$
as $n\to\infty$, I don't know if the factor $\log\log n$ in RHS of previous is the most suitable.

### References:

[1] J. Sondow, *Ramanujan primes and Bertrand's postulate*, Amer. Math. Monthly, 116 (7): 630–635 (2009).